# Como seleccionar el selector CSS correcto

Tags: javascript, html, css, prestashop

estamos aplicando el módulo de facetas en prestashop, el mismo nos arroja un bug en el cual aparece por duplicado en inglés la expresión "en stock", queremos eliminarla y navegando hemos encontrado que es posible mediante css aplicarle un display: none, sin embargo no sabemos muy bien qué selector aplicar al respecto

Parece ser que es una clase que se va generando de forma dinámica en cada una de las categorías de productos que tenemos en nuestra web, de tal manera que no nos vale con seleccionar la clase en específico, ya que en cada categoría cambia

el código es el siguiente:

```html
<div id="search_filters_wrapper" class="hidden-sm-down _mPS2id-t mPS2id-target mPS2id-target-first mPS2id-target-last">
  <div id="search_filter_controls" class="hidden-md-up">
      <span id="_mobile_search_filters_clear_all"></span>
      <button class="btn btn-secondary ok">
        <i class="material-icons rtl-no-flip"></i>
        OK
      </button>
  </div>
            <div id="search_filters">
    
      <p class="text-uppercase h6 hidden-sm-down">Filtrar por</p>

          <section class="facet clearfix">
        <p class="h6 facet-title hidden-sm-down">Precio</p>
                                          
        <div class="title hidden-md-up" data-target="#facet_83566" data-toggle="collapse">
          <p class="h6 facet-title">Precio</p>
          <span class="navbar-toggler collapse-icons">
            <i class="material-icons add"></i>
            <i class="material-icons remove"></i>
          </span>
        </div>

                  
                          <ul id="facet_83566" class="faceted-slider collapse" data-slider-min="44" data-slider-max="115" data-slider-id="83566" data-slider-values="null" data-slider-unit="€" data-slider-label="Precio" data-slider-specifications="{&quot;symbol&quot;:[&quot;,&quot;,&quot;.&quot;,&quot;;&quot;,&quot;%&quot;,&quot;-&quot;,&quot;+&quot;,&quot;E&quot;,&quot;\u00d7&quot;,&quot;\u2030&quot;,&quot;\u221e&quot;,&quot;NaN&quot;],&quot;currencyCode&quot;:&quot;EUR&quot;,&quot;currencySymbol&quot;:&quot;\u20ac&quot;,&quot;positivePattern&quot;:&quot;#,##0.00\u00a0\u00a4&quot;,&quot;negativePattern&quot;:&quot;-#,##0.00\u00a0\u00a4&quot;,&quot;maxFractionDigits&quot;:2,&quot;minFractionDigits&quot;:2,&quot;groupingUsed&quot;:true,&quot;primaryGroupSize&quot;:3,&quot;secondaryGroupSize&quot;:3}" data-slider-encoded-url="https://asalvo.com/es/andadores">
                <li>
                  <p id="facet_label_83566">44,00&nbsp;€ - 115,00&nbsp;€</p>

                  <div id="slider-range_83566" class="ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" aria-disabled="false"><div class="ui-slider-range ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" style="left: 0%; width: 100%;"></div><a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#" style="left: 0%;"></a><a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#" style="left: 100%;"></a></div>
                </li>
              </ul>
                      
              </section>
          <section class="facet clearfix">
        <p class="h6 facet-title hidden-sm-down">Disponibilidad</p>
                                                                              
        <div class="title hidden-md-up" data-target="#facet_38668" data-toggle="collapse">
          <p class="h6 facet-title">Disponibilidad</p>
          <span class="navbar-toggler collapse-icons">
            <i class="material-icons add"></i>
            <i class="material-icons remove"></i>
          </span>
        </div>

                  
            <ul id="facet_38668" class="collapse">
                 ---- ÉSTE ES EL ELEMENTO QUE QUEREMOS OCULTAR -------             
                <li>
                  <label class="facet-label" for="facet_input_38668_0">
                                          <span class="custom-checkbox">
                        <input id="facet_input_38668_0" data-search-url="https://asalvo.com/es/andadores?q=Disponibilidad-Available" type="checkbox">
                                                  <span class="ps-shown-by-js"><i class="material-icons rtl-no-flip checkbox-checked"></i></span>
                                              </span>
                    
                    <a href="https://asalvo.com/es/andadores?q=Disponibilidad-Available" class="_gray-darker search-link js-search-link" rel="nofollow">
                      Available
                                              <span class="magnitude">(13)</span>
                                          </a>
                  </label>
                </li>
                
                ---------------------------------------------------------
                              
                <li>
                  <label class="facet-label" for="facet_input_38668_1">
                                          <span class="custom-checkbox">
                        <input id="facet_input_38668_1" data-search-url="https://asalvo.com/es/andadores?q=Disponibilidad-En+stock" type="checkbox">
                                                  <span class="ps-shown-by-js"><i class="material-icons rtl-no-flip checkbox-checked"></i></span>
                                              </span>
                    
                    <a href="https://asalvo.com/es/andadores?q=Disponibilidad-En+stock" class="_gray-darker search-link js-search-link" rel="nofollow">
                      En stock
                                              <span class="magnitude">(13)</span>
                                          </a>
                  </label>
                </li>
                              
                <li>
                  <label class="facet-label" for="facet_input_38668_2">
                                          <span class="custom-checkbox">
                        <input id="facet_input_38668_2" data-search-url="https://asalvo.com/es/andadores?q=Disponibilidad-No+disponible" type="checkbox">
                                                  <span class="ps-shown-by-js"><i class="material-icons rtl-no-flip checkbox-checked"></i></span>
                                              </span>
                    
                    <a href="https://asalvo.com/es/andadores?q=Disponibilidad-No+disponible" class="_gray-darker search-link js-search-link" rel="nofollow">
                      No disponible
                                              <span class="magnitude">(1)</span>
                                          </a>
                  </label>
                </li>
                          </ul>
          

              </section>
      </div>





</div>
```

Cualquier ayuda al respecto sería muy bien recibida

Answer (score 3):

Si siempre quieres eliminar el primer elemento de esa lista que aparece, una opción sencilla es recoger los elementos por la `clase` y aplicar `display none` al primero.

```js
//recogemos los elementos con la clase 'facet-label'
var elementos = document.getElementsByClassName("facet-label");
//ocultar elemento primero
elementos[0].style.display = "none";
```

```html
<div id="search_filters_wrapper" class="hidden-sm-down _mPS2id-t mPS2id-target mPS2id-target-first mPS2id-target-last">
  <div id="search_filter_controls" class="hidden-md-up">
      <span id="_mobile_search_filters_clear_all"></span>
      <button class="btn btn-secondary ok">
        <i class="material-icons rtl-no-flip"></i>
        OK
      </button>
  </div>
            <div id="search_filters">
    
      <p class="text-uppercase h6 hidden-sm-down">Filtrar por</p>

          <section class="facet clearfix">
        <p class="h6 facet-title hidden-sm-down">Precio</p>
                                          
        <div class="title hidden-md-up" data-target="#facet_83566" data-toggle="collapse">
          <p class="h6 facet-title">Precio</p>
          <span class="navbar-toggler collapse-icons">
            <i class="material-icons add"></i>
            <i class="material-icons remove"></i>
          </span>
        </div>

                  
                          <ul id="facet_83566" class="faceted-slider collapse" data-slider-min="44" data-slider-max="115" data-slider-id="83566" data-slider-values="null" data-slider-unit="€" data-slider-label="Precio" data-slider-specifications="{&quot;symbol&quot;:[&quot;,&quot;,&quot;.&quot;,&quot;;&quot;,&quot;%&quot;,&quot;-&quot;,&quot;+&quot;,&quot;E&quot;,&quot;\u00d7&quot;,&quot;\u2030&quot;,&quot;\u221e&quot;,&quot;NaN&quot;],&quot;currencyCode&quot;:&quot;EUR&quot;,&quot;currencySymbol&quot;:&quot;\u20ac&quot;,&quot;positivePattern&quot;:&quot;#,##0.00\u00a0\u00a4&quot;,&quot;negativePattern&quot;:&quot;-#,##0.00\u00a0\u00a4&quot;,&quot;maxFractionDigits&quot;:2,&quot;minFractionDigits&quot;:2,&quot;groupingUsed&quot;:true,&quot;primaryGroupSize&quot;:3,&quot;secondaryGroupSize&quot;:3}" data-slider-encoded-url="https://asalvo.com/es/andadores">
                <li>
                  <p id="facet_label_83566">44,00&nbsp;€ - 115,00&nbsp;€</p>

                  <div id="slider-range_83566" class="ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" aria-disabled="false"><div class="ui-slider-range ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" style="left: 0%; width: 100%;"></div><a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#" style="left: 0%;"></a><a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#" style="left: 100%;"></a></div>
                </li>
              </ul>
                      
              </section>
          <section class="facet clearfix">
        <p class="h6 facet-title hidden-sm-down">Disponibilidad</p>
                                                                              
        <div class="title hidden-md-up" data-target="#facet_38668" data-toggle="collapse">
          <p class="h6 facet-title">Disponibilidad</p>
          <span class="navbar-toggler collapse-icons">
            <i class="material-icons add"></i>
            <i class="material-icons remove"></i>
          </span>
        </div>

                  
            <ul id="facet_38668" class="collapse">
                 ---- ÉSTE ES EL ELEMENTO QUE QUEREMOS OCULTAR -------             
                <li>
                  <label class="facet-label" for="facet_input_38668_0">
                                          <span class="custom-checkbox">
                        <input id="facet_input_38668_0" data-search-url="https://asalvo.com/es/andadores?q=Disponibilidad-Available" type="checkbox">
                                                  <span class="ps-shown-by-js"><i class="material-icons rtl-no-flip checkbox-checked"></i></span>
                                              </span>
                    
                    <a href="https://asalvo.com/es/andadores?q=Disponibilidad-Available" class="_gray-darker search-link js-search-link" rel="nofollow">
                      Available
                                              <span class="magnitude">(13)</span>
                                          </a>
                  </label>
                </li>
                
                ---------------------------------------------------------
                              
                <li>
                  <label class="facet-label" for="facet_input_38668_1">
                                          <span class="custom-checkbox">
                        <input id="facet_input_38668_1" data-search-url="https://asalvo.com/es/andadores?q=Disponibilidad-En+stock" type="checkbox">
                                                  <span class="ps-shown-by-js"><i class="material-icons rtl-no-flip checkbox-checked"></i></span>
                                              </span>
                    
                    <a href="https://asalvo.com/es/andadores?q=Disponibilidad-En+stock" class="_gray-darker search-link js-search-link" rel="nofollow">
                      En stock
                                              <span class="magnitude">(13)</span>
                                          </a>
                  </label>
                </li>
                              
                <li>
                  <label class="facet-label" for="facet_input_38668_2">
                                          <span class="custom-checkbox">
                        <input id="facet_input_38668_2" data-search-url="https://asalvo.com/es/andadores?q=Disponibilidad-No+disponible" type="checkbox">
                                                  <span class="ps-shown-by-js"><i class="material-icons rtl-no-flip checkbox-checked"></i></span>
                                              </span>
                    
                    <a href="https://asalvo.com/es/andadores?q=Disponibilidad-No+disponible" class="_gray-darker search-link js-search-link" rel="nofollow">
                      No disponible
                                              <span class="magnitude">(1)</span>
                                          </a>
                  </label>
                </li>
                          </ul>
          

              </section>
      </div>





</div>
```

Comment: Hola! he probado tu solución pero no parece que funcione, no hay alguna forma de aplicar directamente el código mediante CSS??

Comment: He probado con .facet-label:first-of-type{ display: none; }, pero me oculta el bloque completo, no la primera opción del filtro :/

Comment: Por alguna razón, también se me aplica al bloque completo ¿que se me escapa exactamente? parece que esos selectores no se aplican sólo al primero, sino a cada facet-label, habrá que aplicarlo a un padre superior?

Comment: por css a mi me funciona .collapse li:first-child { display: none; } que oculta el primer elemento de la lista, con la clase .facet-label se repite como primer elemento dentro de cada <li> y oculta todos

Comment: Vale, si funciona, el problema es que también le afecta al resto de filtros, por ejemplo ahora el filtro de precios no me muestra tampoco la primera de las opciones :(

Comment: es el problema con clases generales css, para que sea sólo en ese listado habría que hacerlo por id (facet_38668) pero no sé si este id cambia

Comment: Así es, el ID va cambiando porque se genera dinámicamente, entonces no hay ninguna otra solución?

Comment: ahora mismo sólo se me ocurre buscar el id por javascript tras generarse y aplicar la propiedad css a ese id

Comment: cómo podría aplicarse ese código mediante javascript??

Answer (score 1):

ese li es estatico de HTML? si es asi, probaste darle una clase y declarar esa clase con display:none en el CSS?:

HTML:

```
<li class="hideable">
                  <label class="facet-label" for="facet_input_38668_0">
                                          <span class="custom-checkbox">
                        <input id="facet_input_38668_0" data-search-url="https://asalvo.com/es/andadores?q=Disponibilidad-Available" type="checkbox">
                                                  <span class="ps-shown-by-js"><i class="material-icons rtl-no-flip checkbox-checked"></i></span>
                                              </span>
                    
                    <a href="https://asalvo.com/es/andadores?q=Disponibilidad-Available" class="_gray-darker search-link js-search-link" rel="nofollow">
                      Available
                                              <span class="magnitude">(13)</span>
                                          </a>
                  </label>
                </li>
```

CSS:

```
.hideable{
display:none}
```

Comment: Hola Carlos, no, me temo que es un elemento que se va creando de forma dinámica, es a través de un plugin de prestashop, el plugin cuando entras en una categoría genera ese elemento automáticamente (además le asigna una nueva ID cada vez que  accedes) así que no sé si una opción sería asignarle una nueva clase a ese elemento cada vez que se crea con javascript (cosa que desconozco)

Comment: Acabo de releer y vi que probaste con 
.facet-label:first-of-type{ display: none; }, pero me oculta el bloque completo, no la primera opción del filtro

Comment: Vi que queres probar con JS, prueba esto:
....
let $li = document.querySelectorAll('.collapse li')
$li[0].classList.add('display-none')....
Y agregar 
....
.display-none{
display:none;
}....